# List of PrintCapabilities using System.Printing is showing different names than windows print queue

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core

I'm getting a list of PageMediaSize using System.Printing.PrintQueue.GetCapabilities. The results of the list show names like NorthAmericaLetter, ISOA4, ISOA5 and JISB5 etc which is different to the list showing in the Windows printer driver which is showing Letter 8.5"x11", A4, A5, B5. Is there a way to get the same list as the Windows printer driver to be returned?